# How to convert retrofit JSON response into List?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, retrofit2

Client (Retrofit) requested all skills stored at server (Rest api), which returns a list of skills as JSON array from the `Skill` Database Table.

I want `List<Skill>`(Skill is a POJO class) at client. How can I convert Json response into list.

here is my code:

method of controller class(Server):

```
@GetMapping(path = "/skill/all")
    public List<Skill> getAllSkills() {
        List<Skill> skills = skillRepo.findAll();

        for (Skill s : skills) {
            String path = s.getImagePath();
            String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                    .path(IMAGEPATH+path)
                    .toUriString();
            s.setImagePath(fileDownloadUri);
        }

        return skills;
    }
```

SkillActivity.java (Client):

```
Retrofit retrofit =apiClient.getRetrofitInstance();
SkillApiService skillApiService = retrofit.create(SkillApiService.class);
        Call<Skill> call = skillApiService.getAllSkills();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Skill>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Skill> call, Response<Skill> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null){
                    List<Skill> listSkills = new ArrayList<>();

                    //here in List<Skill>, I want to store response, which will be pass in recycerview adapter below

                    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_skill);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),3));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listSkills));
                 }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Skill> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("onFailure",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

ApiClient.java

```
public Class ApiClient{
    private static final String BASE_URL = “http://ip:port”;
    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){
        return new  Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(BASE_URL).build();
}
```

SkillApiService.java

```
public interface SkillApiService {

    @GET("/skill/all")
    Call<Skill> getAllSkills();
}
```

JsonResponse: It gives the skill table values.

```
[
    {
        "skillid":1,
        "name":"äbc",
        "imagePath":"<path>",
        "imageName":"abc.png",
        "imagesize":200
    },
    {
        "skillid":2,
        "name":"xyz",
        "imagePath":"<path>",
        "imageName":"xyz.png",
        "imagesize":200
    }
]
```

How do I get the List?

Comment: your interface should declare `Call<List<Skill>>` instead

Comment: That gives an error: Mismatched input exception

Comment: what does the json of the response looks like?

Comment: I have updated question with json response.

Comment: update post with how `retrofit` object in `retrofit.create(SkillApiService.class)` is built

Comment: please check updated post.

Comment: The JSON response which you posted is invalid, all the keys should be wrapped by double-quotes.

Comment: Updated with correct JSON response.

Comment: You have to use `List<Skill>` everywhere. If you get some exception then try to resolve that.

Comment: That giver me TypeMismatchInput exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this conversion you should use a [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html)

```
List<Skill> participantJsonList = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<Skill>>(){});
```

Comment: hey, what should I write in jsonString. I have a response of type POJO  class. I am getting an error cannot deserialize instance of Skill out of START_ARRAY token

Comment: @rupal3112, please convert your json array to json string. thank you